# Display helm-ag in helm-mini

Tags: helm

I recently discovered `helm-ag`, and like its functionality. For some reason, though, I have to enter the pattern to search and then press <kbd>Return</kbd> to actually get the `helm-ag` buffer to appear in `helm-mini`. Is this something that needs to be manually configured? Part of my setup for helm consists of

```
(require 'helm-ag)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'helm-ag-this-file)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
```

and I was hoping that this would be enough to get things to appear in `helm-mini` like the rest of the helm commands (like `helm-M-x` does without any apparent additional setup).